# Verb stem plus や meaning

Tags: grammar, verbs

I came across the following sentence:

> ワタシをわすれちゃいやだよ

I'm guessing it means something like:

> You forgot me!

But what is happening / what is the meaning with the `や` being attached to `ちゃう`'s verb stem?

Comment: If that is the case what is `いや`? Because I would expect `だめ`, `いけない`, or `ならない` instead of `いや`

Comment: I deleted the comment because I didn't want to be answering in the comments, but いや is this https://jisho.org/word/%E5%AB%8C

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If I expand `わすれちゃ` to `わすれては` the only grammar I know that uses this is the setup for `Must not X` and then I would expect `だめ`, `いけない`, or `ならない` following it. For example, I would expect the expanded version of the above to be something like `わすれてはだめだ` (You must not forget)

Comment: Other things can follow ては, since it's just another form of conditional, but I'll let someone else answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure ちゃ is the shortened form of ては. では/ては can be used in a similar way to the conditional たら, but only for negative results. For example:

> 忙しい時に、仕事を休まれては困ります。 
> It will be a problem if you skip work when we are busy.

There are many other ways to use this grammar point, including what you mentioned in the comments.

> そうしなくてはいけません。
> そうしなくちゃいけません。
> You have to do it that way.

For your example, if you expand the sentence, it should become:

> 私を忘れては**いや**だよ。
> If you forgot me I would feel bad. (literal translation) 
> I don't want you to forget me. (natural translation)

いや・嫌 here just expresses that the speaker is emotionally opposed to this happening. So "If you forgot me, I would have negative emotions."
I hope this helps :)